# Efficiently pack variable sized values into buffer

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

## Problem

I am looking for the most efficient way to pack a list of values into a numpy array. The values list consists of mixes between singular values and differently sized lists of singular values, where the size of each element is known ahead of time. My current method is shown below.

```
buffer = np.zeros(10)
lengths = [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1]
values = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 6, [7, 8, 9], 10]

idx = 0
for dlen, val in zip(lengths, values):
  if dlen == 1:
    buffer[idx] = val
  else:
    buffer[idx:idx+dlen] = val
  idx += dlen

print(buffer)  # [ 1.  2.  3.  4.  5.  6.  7.  8.  9. 10.]
```

This is the desired behavior for my application. I provide some background and explanation below. This operation ends up being linear with `len(lengths)` or `len(values)` (they are the same). My question is if there is a method I could use which would either be sub-linear with the number of lengths or more efficient in general?

## Background

I am working on an internal data-logging library using h5py. The data log is split into different elements, where each element consists of a dataset for the times and another dataset for the values of each sample point. When writing to multiple elements at a time, the I/O can cause significant overhead, especially when collecting data as a "group" (collecting a set of temperatures or voltages) since each time-point and data-point must be written to individually. I have overcome this problem by exercising HDF5 virtual datasets to configure a single dataset for each group of measurements and then use virtual datasets to slice each column of the source dataset into a separate element. This groups all the I/O into the same operation, thus greatly improving performance of logging data. The improvement has come to the point where in certain conditions, the packing of the values into the buffer takes longer than the I/O itself.

Comment: Question: why are you separating time and sample point value data? Why not create 1 dataset with the times with the values of each sample point?

Comment: Times are recorded as uint64, using nanoseconds since epoch. The values can be a number of different datatypes.

Comment: HDF5, Bumpy and h5py support mixed data types. Create a record array with type uint64 and values of appropriate type and you are set. Much simpler and easier than multiple datasets and I/O is easier to handle.

Comment: I agree this would be the best way to exercise the capabilities of the mentioned libraries (numpy*). Unfortunately, the data ingestion service my company uses doesn't support this, as it was originally intended to ingest separate arrays for the time data and the value data. We had to kind of shoehorn in HDF5 ingestion support and this is how they decided to support it, by making HDF5 versions of the original home-grown file format.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```py
In [30]: import numpy as  np

In [31]: from pandas.core.common import flatten

In [32]: values = [1, 2, 3, [4, 5], 6, [7, 8, 9], 10] 

In [33]: np.array(list(flatten(values)))
Out[33]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

Comment: This code is certainly cleaner to look at, but unfortunately, this turns the operation from linear with the number of elements in lengths to linear with total number of elements.